# Can I just use the packages in my package diagram as the entities for my class diagram?

Tags: class, package, uml

We need to create a booking system that allows rape victims to book sessions with a counsellor (who is a volunteer therefore is not on duty 24/7) online. The organisation used to do the booking process over the phone, writing down important information.

This is the package diagram I created for a project. I am not sure: am I allowed to just use the packages as entities for the class diagram?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A package is a tool to structure models by grouping somehow related pieces into namespaces.

It is not unusual to recognize a decomposition that coincides somehow with larger components (e.g. Client, Application and Data).  But it is not correct to use packages as a substitute for a class. It may even look confusing.

It is not a problem to keep enclosing or nested packages such as `Booking system` in a class diagram. But you should use a proper class box for classes. You would then be able to show not only the properties but also the operations in a different compartment.  Last but not least, you could be more precise in the relationships between classes, considering that packages are only related via dependencies and some special package operations, whereas classes can be related also with associations, inheritance, etc..

For example, your diagram tells only that `Booking` is dependent on `Client`. And this means the content of one package needs to know about the other packages.  But in reality `Client` and `Booking` should be associated  i.e. an instance of `Client` would be related for a longer time to some specific instances of `Booking`. In this case, you'd expect that you could easily navigate from the one to the other.  Associations also allow to specify multiplicity, e.g. that one client could have 1 or more bookings, but each booking would be for only one client.

Other remarks, unrelated to the question:

- Your comment box suggests that you try to explain the purpose of the system, perhaps for some stakeholders.  You may therefore consider using a use-case diagram to show the big picture with the different actors and the goals they want to achieve with the system.
- In a class box, you could add an «Entity» stereotype above the name of the class.  Entities are domain classes that matter to the users.
- Data storage system seems not to fit in the diagram:  it's not really an entity.  Perhaps it's a class, a component or a package, but not really an entity.